# How to split hours in a timesheet to account for working after midnight?

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, sum, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm using geolocation to automatically record my work hours.  But, as I often work after midnight, I need to automatically "split" the hours into each day they were worked. The final result desired is just the hours worked each day, per row `Jan 1st - 2 hours`

For example: if I start work on the 1st/Jan, and work 10pm to 2am, then two hours should be billed to the 1/Jan and the other two hours to 2/Jan.

Below is example automatically generated data, based on when I physically enter the work area.

[image: Example Data]

So, one possible solution would be to transpose this list horizontally, and add logic that says "if not exited by midnight, then add entries "exited: 23:59" & "entered: 00:00" the next day)

In this case, the next step might look like:

[image: Possible Solution]

But I don't know how to transpose(?) the data, or automatically generate the missing fields, in Google Sheets. Or perhaps there is a better solution?

[Editable copy of spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15SF3Gn_cn4ZpjonEAyu0vVwgdf7xsCGdWjeZ7o462MQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Done, [shared link here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15SF3Gn_cn4ZpjonEAyu0vVwgdf7xsCGdWjeZ7o462MQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR({DATEVALUE(F2:F), G2:G}), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''"))
```

[image: 0]

---

E2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({QUERY(
 IFERROR(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(B1:B, A1:A="entered"), " at ", "♦"), "♦")), 
 "select Col1+Col2 label Col1+Col2''"); IFERROR(
 IF(INDEX(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(B:B, A:A="exited"), " at ", "♦"), "♦"),,1)<>
 INDEX(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(B1:B, A1:A="entered"), " at ", "♦"), "♦"),,1), 
 INDEX(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(B1:B, A1:A="entered"), " at ", "♦"), "♦"),,1)+
 "23:59:59.999",))}, "where Col1 is not null order by Col1", 0))
```

F2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(B:B, A:A="exited"), " at ", "♦"), "♦")),,99^99))*1; IFERROR(
 IF(INDEX(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(B:B, A:A="exited"), " at ", "♦"), "♦"),,1)<>
 INDEX(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(B:B, A:A="entered"), " at ", "♦"), "♦"),,1), 
 INDEX(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(B:B, A:A="entered"), " at ", "♦"), "♦"),,1)
 +"23:59:59", ))}, "where Col1 is not null order by Col1", 0))
```

G2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(F2:F="",,F2:F-E2:E))
```